# Funções PHP + MySQLi

Tags: php, mysqli

Criei uma função em `php` para o `cruid` no banco de dados porem a função `Read` esta com problema e não consigo entender o porque, segue o codigo:

```
function DBRead($table,  $params = null, $fields = "*"){
    $table  = DB_PREFIX . '_' . $table;
    $params = ($params) ? " {$params}" : null;

    $query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
    $result = DBExecute($query);

    if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
        return $query;
    else{
        while ($rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $data[] =$rs;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**DB_PREFIX** é uma constante apenas pra auxiliar na seleção da tabela no banco de dados, a linha que estou tentando executar é essa:

```
    $chekDouble = DBRead('postagem', "WHERE titulo = '" . $form['titulo'] . "'" );
```

fiz o debug com `var_dump()` e a saida é essa :

```
'SELECT * FROM mg_postagem WHERE titulo = 'titulo''
```

esse `SELECT` verifica se o titulo que o usuário esta inserindo já é titulo de alguma outra postagem no banco de dados, ***porem e ele sempre retorna***`true`  obs: a base de dados está vazia...

```
if( $chekDouble )
            echo 'Titulo de Post Já cadastrado!';
        else{

            if(DBCreate('postagem',$form))
```

o titule provem de um formulário e utilizo o método `$_POST`, para a função de inserção são passados por parâmetros nome da tabela, e um `array` de campos e valores. esse é o array.

```
$form['titulo'] = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['titulo'] ) );
$form['bloco1'] = strip_tags( trim( $_POST['bloco1'] ) );
$form['bloco2'] = trim( $_POST['bloco2'] );
$form['datapost']= date("Y-m-d");
```

obs: a função funciona quando uso dessa forma:

```
$teste = DBRead('postagem', "teste" );
```

quem executa todas as `query` é:

```
function DBExecute($query){
    $link   = DBConnect();
    $result = @mysqli_query($link,$query) or die(mysqli_error($link));

    DBClose($link);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: `$checkDouble` armazena o resultado da função `DBRead();` antes do `if ($checkDouble)` tem isso `$chekDouble = DBRead('postagem', "WHERE titulo = '" . $form['titulo'] . "'" );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema parece ser que a sua consulta falha por um erro de sintaxe de pois tem o `if` que é avaliado sempre como true.

Na montagem da sua consulta certifique-se de espaçar as clásulas

```
$query  = "SELECT {$fields} FROM {$table}{$params}";
//Adicione um espaço aqui --------------^

if(!mysqli_num_rows($result))
    return $query;// mude por return false;
```

Ao invés de retornar uma string com algum texto(consulta sql) que será avaliada como `true` no if, retorne apenas `false`, uma ideia é criar uma outra função que faz o log das consultas geradas por `dbRead()` antes do `return false`.

Com essa alteração o if deve funcionar conforme o esperado:

```
$chekDouble = DBRead('postagem', "WHERE titulo = '" . $form['titulo'] . "'" );

if( $chekDouble )
   echo 'Titulo de Post Já cadastrado!';
else{
  if(DBCreate('postagem',$form))
```

Comment: `DBRead` não executa a função de leitura `sql`, ela apenas constroi a query, quem executa a função é a função `DBExecute`

Comment: @HebertdeLima, em `DBEexecute()` no `mysqli_query()` lembre dar um `or die(mysqli_error($conexao));` para saber de ocorreu algum erro.

Comment: isso já ocorre, a variável `$link` retorna a conexão! `$link = DBConnect()`

Comment: nossa cara, era isso mesmo, eu estava retornando um `array` no `return` do `DBRead` como você disse, o certo é `false`! muito obrigado!